# How to write multiple records in a JSON file?

Tags: json.net

I cannot find this any where. I am using the newton JSON control and trying to loop through my records and write each record in one JSON file. Below is what I was trying but can't get it right. I get token path errors and all sorts. I don't know where to put the start and end for writing the JSON.

Thanks!
Warren

```
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
    Using writer As JsonWriter = New JsonTextWriter(sw)
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        writer.WriteStartObject()

        Dim ConnString7 As String = "removed"
        Dim SQLConn As New SqlConnection()
        Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand()
        SQLCmd.Connection = SQLConn
        SQLConn.ConnectionString = ConnString7
        SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        SQLCmd.CommandText = "Sproc_Here"
        SQLConn.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        reader = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            MsgBox("Start")
            writer.WritePropertyName("CardDate")
            writer.WriteValue(reader("CardDate").ToString())
            writer.WritePropertyName("EditDate")
            writer.WriteValue(reader("EditDate").ToString())
            writer.WritePropertyName("Activity")
            writer.WriteValue(reader("Activity").ToString())
            writer.WritePropertyName("Location")
            writer.WriteValue(reader("Location").ToString())
            MsgBox("End")
        End While
        reader.Close()
        SQLConn.Close()

        writer.WriteEnd()
        writer.WriteEndObject()

        MsgBox(sb.ToString)

        Response.Clear()
        Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        Response.Write(sb.ToString)
        Response.End()
```

Answer (score 0):

Each record will become a JSON object, and you want to have multiple of them, so they need to be enclosed in a JSON array.  So something like this:

```
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
    Using writer As JsonWriter = New JsonTextWriter(sw)

        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented

        ' ... code to set up SQLCmd omitted for brevity ...
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader()

        writer.WriteStartArray()

        While reader.Read()
            writer.WriteStartObject()
            writer.WritePropertyName("CardDate")
            writer.WriteValue(reader("CardDate").ToString())
            writer.WritePropertyName("EditDate")
            writer.WriteValue(reader("EditDate").ToString())
            writer.WritePropertyName("Activity")
            writer.WriteValue(reader("Activity").ToString())
            writer.WritePropertyName("Location")
            writer.WriteValue(reader("Location").ToString())
            writer.WriteEndObject()
        End While

        writer.WriteEndArray()

        ' ... code to close connection and write response omitted ...

    End Using
```